# Styling HTML select/option element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a select box that looks like this:

[image]

And the HTML code to generate it:

```
<select data-ng-attr-size="{{items.length}}" class="itemsList">
    <option class="item-edit" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="itemSelected(item)">Item Title: {{item.ItemTitle}}, Color: {{item.ItemColor}}</option>
</select>
```

What I am trying to do is get it so all the "Color: colors" text lines up in a column. How could I use html or css to do this?

Comment: You can't do this with a standard select element.

Comment: You are limited in what can be done with `<select>`, and with no way to target the text within the `<option>` you cannot exactly apply any sort of margins to create a faux-column look.  Your best option would be to use a JS solution that replicates the `<select>` element.

Comment: Selects are notoriously difficult to customize, and it's impossible on some platforms.  You would need to use a 3rd party replacement such as [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating).

Comment: Most solutions combine JS with a UL and LI layout, check this demo: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/#

Comment: The best you can do is just add three or four spaces between each element. It won't be attractive and it certainly won't be uniform, but it would be a bit easier to read. It's impossible to have columns in a select list.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a monospace font and just calculate how many spaces you need to insert between the item title and color.